# Why Will ROOT Only Let Me Set The Final Element of a TCanvas Vector to Another TCanvas Vector if I Pass the Vector to Another Class?

Tags: c++, qt, root-framework, tcanvas

### The Problem

I want to start dynamically passing a TCanvas from essentially the "Model" part of my program to the "View" part. The way I thought about doing this, was to simply create my TCanvas on the View at startup, then update this TCanvas with the View TCanvas once the graphs had been filled. I created a test bench to see if it would work.

I've displayed a working method and the broken method.

I'm using QT-ROOT, the [TQtWidget](http://root.cern.ch/root/html528/TQtWidget.html) is a custom widget which is essentially a back to the TCanvas.

### Setting Up My Canvas

```
void DataTestTab::setupCanvas(int cNCbc) //I pass "2" to this for now to generate the below loop twice
{
    for (int i=0; i<cNCbc; i++)
    {
        m_vectorCanvas.push_back(new TQtWidget(this));

        //m_vectorCanvas[i]->GetCanvas()->SetFillColor(i);
        QHBoxLayout *loH = new QHBoxLayout(this);

        loH->addWidget(m_vectorCanvas[i]);
        m_vectorLayout.push_back(loH);

        QGroupBox *gbCanvas = new QGroupBox(this);
        QString title = QString("CBC %1").arg(i);
        gbCanvas->setTitle(title);
        gbCanvas->setLayout(m_vectorLayout[i]);
        m_vectorGroupBox.push_back(gbCanvas);

        ui->loCbcBox->addWidget(m_vectorGroupBox[i]); //adding the panels to the main layout
    }
}
```

### This Works

```
void DataTestTab::drawTest()
    {
        static Int_t HistoID = 1;
        qDebug() << "in Testing env ";
        std::vector<TH1D*> graphs;
        std::vector<TCanvas*> vCanvas;

        TString name("h1_");
        Bool_t build = false;


        for (int i = 0; i <m_vectorCanvas.size() ; i++)
        {
            TCanvas *cCanvas = new TCanvas(build);
            name += HistoID++;

            vCanvas.push_back(cCanvas);
            vCanvas.at(i)->cd();


            TH1D *h1 = new TH1D(name.Data(),name.Data(),10,0, 10);
            graphs.push_back(h1);
            graphs.at(i)->Fill(i);

            graphs.at(i)->Draw();
            //graphs.at(i)->DrawCopy();

            m_vectorCanvas.at(i)->GetCanvas()->SetFillColor(i+5);
            m_vectorCanvas.at(i)->cd();

            qDebug() << i;

            m_vectorCanvas.at(i)->GetCanvas()->SetCanvas(vCanvas.at(i));
            m_vectorCanvas.at(i)->Refresh();
        }
    }
```

Corresponding output:

[image: Working Method]

Albeit the graphs are in the wrong order.

### This Does Not Work

I transfer this method to another class and pass the TCanvas back over signal/slots.

```
 void DataTestWorker::doWork()
    {
        static Int_t HistoID = 1;
        qDebug() << "in Testing env ";
        std::vector<TH1D*> graphs;
        std::vector<TCanvas*> vCanvas;

        TString name("h1_");
        Bool_t build = false;

        for (int i = 0; i <2 ; i++)
        {
            TCanvas *cCanvas = new TCanvas(build);
            name += HistoID++;

            vCanvas.push_back(cCanvas);
            vCanvas.at(i)->cd();

            TH1D *h1 = new TH1D(name.Data(),name.Data(),10,0, 10);
            graphs.push_back(h1);
            graphs.at(i)->Fill(i);

            graphs.at(i)->Draw();

        }
        emit sendGraphData(vCanvas); //void sendGraphData(const std::vector<TCanvas*> &canvas);
```

The graph data is then sent to here:

```
void DataTestTab::drawGraph(const std::vector<TCanvas*> &canvas)
{
    for (int i=0; i<m_vectorCanvas.size(); i++)
    {
        canvas.at(i)->cd();
        m_vectorCanvas.at(i)->cd();
        m_vectorCanvas.at(i)->GetCanvas()->SetCanvas(canvas.at(i));
        m_vectorCanvas.at(i)->Refresh();
        //m_vectorCanvas.at(i)->GetCanvas()->Update();

    }
}
```

This is the output of this method:

[image: Attempt 2]

The only error I can see at the moment is I get this for the SetupTab:

```
QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to GUI::DataTestTab "DataTestTab", which already has a layout
QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to GUI::DataTestTab "DataTestTab", which already has a layout
```

Comment: can you produce a minimal example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to recreate the problem?

Comment: @Erik So a complete working piece of code that people can copy and paste?

Comment: @Erik - though how many people use QT-ROOT?

Comment: the point is that e.g. I don't see the problem right away but might be able to help if can reproduce the problem so that I can try different things. With the current code I'd have to construct a class around it to make it compile and make sure that I don't leave something important out. That's why a self-contained example is helpful.

Comment: @Erik Do you have QT-ROOT? If so I will make you a small version of the above tonight!

Comment: I do have Qt Root. I obviously cannot promise that I can solve the issue at hand, but I can take a look at least.

Comment: @Erik The project is huge and it is taking some time to translate. I think the problem lies with my Worker Class above being in a thread - QPixMap hates doing things when it's threaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am trying to tackle thing one at a time. Your error message `QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to GUI::DataTestTab "DataTestTab", which already has a layout` stems from the fact that you are calling this constructor for your QHBoxLayout:

```
QHBoxLayout *loH = new QHBoxLayout(this);
```

If you look at the documentation for `QLayout` (e.g. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlayout.html#QLayout) then you are calling the constructor with a parent (in your case `this`) and the documentation says:

```
QLayout::QLayout ( QWidget * parent )
Constructs a new top-level QLayout, with parent parent. parent may not be 0.
There can be only one top-level layout for a widget.
```

So even if you don't explicitly set these layouts as the main layout of your `DataTestTab`, Qt tries to do this because this is how the constructor is written and this results in the message you are seeing.

The obvious cure for this problem is to change

```
QHBoxLayout *loH = new QHBoxLayout(this);
```

to

```
QHBoxLayout *loH = new QHBoxLayout;
```

which then calls this constructor:

```
QLayout::QLayout ()
Constructs a new child QLayout.
This layout has to be inserted into another layout before geometry management will work.
```

i.e. a `QLayout` that can be added to another one (and has to in order to work).

EDIT: 
I think you can simplify your way of handing over objects. There is no reason to construct a `TCanvas` for each histogram and pass it around, especially since the `TCanvas` will not take ownership of your histogram and I believe that when you issue `TH1::Draw()` even having `cd()`'ed into the canvas you want, this does not achieve what you are trying to do.

I played with your code and I could achieve what you want by simply having:

```
void DataTestWorker::doWork()
{
  static Int_t HistoID = 1;
  std::vector<TH1D*> graphs;
  TString name("h1_");
  for (int i = 0; i <2 ; i++)
    {
      name += HistoID++;
      TH1D *h1 = new TH1D(name.Data(),name.Data(),10,0, 10);
      graphs.push_back(h1);
      graphs.at(i)->Fill(i);
    }
  emit sendGraphData(graphs); //void sendGraphData(std::vector<TH1D*>);     

}
```

and

```
void DataTestTab::drawGraph(std::vector<TH1D*> hists)
{
  for (size_t i=0; i<m_vectorCanvas.size(); i++)
    {
      TH1D *h = hists.at(i);
      m_vectorCanvas.at(i)->cd();
      h->Draw();
      m_vectorCanvas.at(i)->Refresh();
    }
}
```

I obviously do not perform any checks to make sure that the `std::vector<TH1D*>` and `std::vector<TQtWidget*>` have the same length etc. but with this code I was able to display two histograms on the two `TCanvas` as you showed in your `This Works` example.

Does this help?

Comment: Thankyou for your very detailed answer. I'm booting up my laptop now and will check through this asap.

Comment: The internet is so slow here, it took me this long to update it. I just tried it out and it worked. Both things. I don't think I can reward you enough with just a "correct answer" status.

Comment: that's ok. If the answer is useful you can also up-vote it by clicking on the up arrow next to it. Other than that: you're welcome

Comment: I already did =P There's barely any up to date documentation on QT-ROOT.